# Part of the webpage on a new window

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, html

If I have some hidden element on a page, that contains some content, how can I create a link and when user clicks it, browser would open a new window and show the content (only the content, for example some json data)?

ps. I know that's probably bad idea to have some hidden content on the page. It's better to put an action link that  will get the content from the server.. But it involves many other headaches and it wasn't me who created the page, so please just let me know if there's a comparatively easy solution...

Comment: A "real" new browser window? Or only a modal window, like a [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/docs/dialog/)?

Comment: I don't know. Basically I'd like to present json data in new tab/window. Or... maybe there's a way to send json data to some online json viewer so users can see json data in more readable form?

Answer (score 0):

Please use http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/index.html with inline content setting

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the (URL encoded) contents of the hidden element as an argument in the URL when opening the second page. That argument could then be (unencoded and) inserted into the body of the second page when it loads.

The following example works locally on OS X. On other operating systems, the example may need to be placed on an actual web server before it will work:

**page1.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Page 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function openwindow(){
    window.open("page2.html?html="+escape($("#myDiv").html()));
}
</script>
<style>
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="javascript:openwindow();">Click Me!</a>

<div class="hidden" id="myDiv">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/HTML5-logo.svg/200px-HTML5-logo.svg.png">
<p>See the HTML5 <a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/">specification</a></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**page2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Page 2</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery.extend({
    // from: http://paulgueller.com/2011/04/26/parse-the-querystring-with-jquery/

    parseQuerystring: function(){
        var nvpair = {};
        var qs = window.location.search.replace('?', '');
        var pairs = qs.split('&');
        $.each(pairs, function(i, v){
            var pair = v.split('=');
            nvpair[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        });
        return nvpair;
    }
});
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document.body).html(unescape(jQuery.parseQuerystring().html));
    });
</script>
<style>
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- this will be replaced -->

</body>
</html>
```